# JavaFX - Resize Window based on loaded image size

Tags: java, layout, javafx

My main `Window`s appearance is defined by an FXML file with a `BorderPane` structure. The `center` tag is defined as follows:

```
<center>
    <ScrollPane focusTraversable="false">
        <content>
            <Pane fx:id="mapArea">
                <ImageView fx:id="mapImageView" />
            </Pane>
        </content>
    </ScrollPane>
</center>
```

In the program, the user can open an image file representing a map, add some points of interests, and save it all for later. The image can be of any size. What I want is for the main window to resize so that when an image is loaded, it fits perfectly in the `ImageView`, although users are allowed to resize manually, for example if the image is too large for their monitor.

Right now in my controller, I execute the following lines when an image is loaded:

```
double width = getMap().getImage().getWidth();
double height = getMap().getImage().getHeight();
mapImageView.prefWidth(width);
mapImageView.prefHeight(height);
```

This has some strange (to me) effects. The height of the window is set so that the image COULD be fully shown if the `ImageView` was the only `Node` in the `Scene`, but obviously it is not. The width of the windows doesn't seem to be affected at all.

I have tried fiddling around with different properties on different objects, `minWidth`, `maxWidth`, `prefWidth`, `setResizeable` and so on, but I feel like I am stumbling in the dark. I don't really know how it all comes together, and this SOUNDS like something that should be trivial.

Please let me know if you require more code.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaFX when you want to set a value to some field X it will typically have a corresponding setX() method.

`prefWidth(double)` and `prefHeight(double)` return node's preferred values for width and height. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#prefWidth-double-

If you want to set the window(JavaFX Stage) size then in your `start(Stage)` method, obtain a reference to the `primaryStage`. Once you've loaded your image, you can do `stage.setWidth(width)` and `stage.setHeight(height)`
Example:

```
public class YourJavaFXApp extends Application {

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        stage = primaryStage;
        // some code here
    }
}
```

If you want to resize the loaded image to fit the current window size instead then you can use `mapImageView.setFitWidth(width)` and `mapImageView.setFitHeight(height)`

Comment: I know that I could set the literal height/width of the window by accessing the stage reference, but then I would have to do the calculations manually, accounting for the size of the menus and other UI elements that take up space in the stage other than the image view. It seems to me like it should be way simpler to just say "this control wants to be this big, please make sure that the container resizes itself accordingly"?

Comment: You already have a `ScrollPane` and a `Pane` wrapped around your `ImageView`. Try calling `setPrefSize(width, height)` on either of them and see if that works.